# Should I use Qt Jambi  in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, qt, qt-jambi

Is it a good idea for me to use Qt Jambi in Java as a toolkit?

I see that Qt Jambi is hard to learn, and Swing is easier than Qt Jambi, but I think that Qt Jambi is more powerful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two years ago, I started a Java Desktop Application and used Swing as a GUI framweork. Up to that point, I had experience with C++/MFC (*shudder*) and C++/Qt (*very nice*).

After trying to get along with Swing for a while (including reading lots of tutorials and even a book) I came to the following conclusion:

**Swing is much more difficult and clumsy than Qt for three reasons:**

1. A lot of simple stuff requires more code than it should.
2. Some things that Qt brings for free are almost impossible to achieve in a reasonable amount of time.
3. Swing doesn't bring a WYSIWYG GUI Editor and I could not find a free one that comes close to Qt's Designer.

I then threw away the Swing GUI, switched to Qt Jambi and was really impressed by it. One weekend later I had a nice Qt GUI and lived happily ever after.

Comment: No Swing GUI editor? What are you talking about?
http://www.netbeans.org/kb/articles/matisse.html
http://www.eclipse.org/vep

Comment: @Tiberiu Ana:
The post does not claim that there are NO free Swing GUI Editors. It just says that they were not as good as Qt's Designer when I tried them.
As the comment of Gili hints, that might have changed within the last 2 years.

Answer (score 3):

If you think being familiar with Qt would be useful in the future, when you might want to develop in C++ (or change some Qt-based software), I think it would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

Qt Jambi is much simple and easier to use than Swing and SWT.

I think that the only default of Qt Jambi is that there is not that much documentation about that and forums answering questions about Qt Jambi are rare (this is the only one i found :D)

Hope this helps.